# Does sqoop preserves order of imported rows as in Database

Tags: jdbc, hive, sql-order-by, sqoop

I am sqooping a table from `oracle database` to `AWS S3` & then creating a `hive` table over it.

After importing the data, is the order of records present in database preserved in hive table?

I want to fetch few hundred rows from database as well as hive using java JDBC then compare each row present in `ResultSet`. Assuming I don't have a primary key, can I compare the rows from both `ResultSets` as they appear(sequentially, using `resultSet.next()`) or does the order gets changed due to parallel import?

If order isn't preserved whether `ORDER BY` is a good option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order is not preserved during import, also order is not determined when selecting without `ORDER BY` or `DISTRIBUTE+SORT` due to parallel select processing.

You need to specify `order by` when selecting data, does not matter how it was inserted.

ORDER BY orders all data, will work on single reducer, DISTRIBUTE BY + SORT orders per reducer and works in distributed mode.

Also see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40264715/2700344