# Add some lines at the top of hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, bigdata, hiveql

I have a table of this form in hive (Before):

```
AB_dimp|SF_0060H00000nhSrmQAE|EBA Order 1127735|Execute|New From
AB_dimp|SF_0060H00000nhSwkQAE|EBA Order 1127725|Execute|New From
AB_Dimp|SF_0060H00000nhSyDQAU|EBA Order 1127728|Execute|New From
```

And I want to put these 3 lines to appear at the top of that table in hive in this form (After):

```
[Yellow]
Cat ID|AN_Net|
[network]
AB_dimp|SF_0060H00000nhSkPQAU|EBA Order 1127708|Execute|New From
AB_DIMP|SF_0060H00000nhSl8QAE|EBA Order 1127709|Execute|New From
AB_DIMP|SF_0060H00000nhSrmQAE|EBA Order 1127735|Execute|New From
```

How can I achieve that in Hive please?

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking about

Comment: Hi @leftjoin, what I'm basically saying is that I want this to come before my hive table above.                                                                                            [hier]
Opportunity ID|SF_AllOpportunities|   How can I hardcode these valuse to appear at the top of the table above?  
[relation]

Comment: but what " to come on top of the table above" means? where this " [hier] Opportunity ID|SF_AllOpportunities| " is in your example

Comment: Are you trying to add some additional row ? Could you please edit the question and make it clear. Now it seems it is a mess a little bit

Comment: Okay, Maybe I didn't word it right so I'll try again. Assuming I have a table and I want to select specific columns of that table (such as the above table). But at the very top of the table, I want to hard code values  "Team" "Legal" "Advocate" at the top of the table.

Comment: Please add this in your example data: before and after, how should it look like. Table contains more columns than you are saying you want to add... Sorry but it is still not clear.

Comment: @leftjoin, No, not new rows. Ok, what can I do to simply add this line at the top of the above table.  "Team"

Comment: do you mean column names to be displayed in the query result? What "add this line at the top of the above table" means  The example also does not reflect what you are saying in the comments. Where are these "Team" "Legal" "Advocate" in the data example?

Comment: If you want to add some line to the query result, then please provide the query also

Comment: @leftjoin. I have tried to edit the question. That's what I'm trying to achieve so that the data in the after file can look like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use union all:

```
select '[Yellow]' as col_name union all
select 'ID|AN_Net|'           union all
select '[network]'            union all
select col_name from your_table;
```

If you want to add these lines in the table, not only select them, you do not need intermediate table to achieve this:

```
insert overwrite your_table 
select * from 
(
    select '[Yellow]' as col_name union all
    select 'ID|AN_Net|'           union all
    select '[network]'            union all
    select col_name from your_table
)s;
```

But bear in mind, that rows in the table are not ordered. When you select table without `order by`, select is being executed in parallel on many mappers. The underlying file(s) are being splitted and mappers read each own splits. They are executed quite isolated from each other in parallel and return results also independently. Which is faster it's result will be returned faster, you see, only order by guarantees the order of rows returned. This means that next time when you select this table with some probability you may have these additional rows returned not as first ones. Only ORDER BY can guarantee the order of rows. And you need to have some column which you can use for ordering rows, like id, or your column can be used in the order by.
If the table is small it is a chance that it will be read on single mapper and rows will be returned in the original order, like in the underlying file.

To preserve order of rows in a file you can add row_order column and use it in the upper query in the ORDER BY:

```
select  DRM_Pln_Parent, opportunityid, opportunity_name
   from
   (
   SELECT 1 as row_order, '[hier]' as DRM_Pln_Parent, '' as opportunityid, '' as opportunity_name
UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 as row_order, 'Opportunity ID|SF_AllOpportunities|' as DRM_Pln_Parent, '' as opportunityid, '' as opportunity_name
UNION ALL
   SELECT 3 as row_order, '[relation]' as DRM_Pln_Parent, '' as opportunityid, '' as opportunity_name
UNION ALL 
   SELECT DISTINCT 4 as row_order, 'SF_AllOpportunities' AS DRM_Pln_Parent, 
CONCAT('SF_',opportunityid) as opportunityid, 
opportunity_name, 
from ...

   )s
order by row_order
```

For better understanding see also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43368113/2700344

Comment: Thanks so much for your contribution. But  the lines I'm trying to add are not coming from any table. I just simply want to hardcode them as is so that they can appear at the very top of the table. Can I still use union all to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @leftjoin, I have used UNION ALL. Two common errors I get are: 1) The abstract syntax tree is null (2) Schema of both sides of union should match...   Here is my query... SELECT '[hier]' AS Hier UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Opportunity ID|SF_AllOpportunities|'   UNION ALL
SELECT '[relation]'  UNION ALL
select DISTINCT 'AB_Allangles' AS CAD_Lsa_Altitude, CONCAT('AB_',opportunityid) as opportunityid,
opportunity_name,
stagename,
opportunity_type,
forecastcategory,
default_opp_weighting as weighting,
iswon,
closeddate
from sf_opportunity
WHERE....

Comment: @Oye Sure, the schema and the number of columns should match. You cannot select different number of columns in different rows in single dataset. Possible solutions is to add other columns also: like null as col2, null as col3.

Comment: I still got this error @leftjoin  "Schema of both sides of union should match" with this query. SELECT '[hier]' AS NULL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Opportunity ID|SF_AllOpportunities|' AS NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT '[relation]' AS NULL  UNION ALL...........
Maybe there is something I'm doing terribly wrong.

Comment: Hi @leftjoin, I managed to write the rows in my select statement using union all, but they all appear on the same line instead of different lines layered on top of each other as shown above. Also, it appears at the bottom of the table instead of the top. Any ideas how to handle both?

Comment: @Oye each line should have the same number of columns: `SELECT '[hier]' as DRM_Pln_Parent, '' as opportunityid, '' as opportunity_name
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Opportunity ID|SF_AllOpportunities|' as DRM_Pln_Parent, '' as opportunityid, '' as opportunity_name
UNION ALL
SELECT  '[relation]' as DRM_Pln_Parent, '' as opportunityid, '' as opportunity_name
UNION ALL 
select DISTINCT 'SF_AllOpportunities' AS DRM_Pln_Parent, 
CONCAT('SF_',opportunityid) as opportunityid, 
opportunity_name, 
from dev_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn...`

Comment: Many Thanks @leftjoin... That worked. One last thing is that the 3 rows are appearing at the buttom of the text file. How can I make it appear at the top? I remember you mentioned using ORDERBY earlier, but that hadn't work yet.

Comment: Hi @leftjoin, Having used the row_order format, and using order by row_order, it seems to be throwing this error...     Invalid table alias or column reference 'row_order'.

Comment: Hi @leftjoin, yes that's what I've done... SELECT 1 as row_order, '[hier]' as DRM_Pln_Parent, NULL as opportunityid,  NULL as opportunity_name, NULL as stagename, etc etc is what I'm using and it's giving Invalid table alias or column reference 'row_order'.

Comment: @Oye looks like you forgot to put constant before row_order it in one of union queries. Provide the whole query pls

Comment: Hi @leftjoin... It has finally worked. You were right, I omitted it outright. Thanks for all the help. Really do appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

a.) First, create another table (let's say, NewTable) and insert these 3 records

b.) Now, insert your existing data into another table

```
insert overwrite table NewTable select * from ExisitngTable;
```

c.) delete ExisitngTable

d.) Now insert data from NewTable to ExisitngTable

```
insert overwrite table ExisitngTable select * from NewTable name;
```

Comment: Thanks. But just I'm trying to do a selection from a table and save the result in a text file. And I want to hard code those 3 records at the top of the table. I'm not trying to insert into another table but simply want to make a selection and save it in a text file.