# How sorting works on Partitioned skewed data set in Hive

Tags: sorting, hadoop, hive, mapreduce, skew

I am having a dataset with below heirarchy in Hive, size of datsets is in TB's.

```
-Country
   -Year
   -In_stock
   -Zone
      -trans_dt
```

I need to sort trans_dt in ascending order within Zone (one of the zone contributes 80% of dataset) which is the most efficient way to sort this dataset. I have total 10 countries and each country holds around 100 Zones.
Once trans_dt is sorted I need to perform operation on collect_sets hence sorting is very important in my case.

I tried partitioning the dataset by Year and then applied Cluster by on trans_dt desc, but it seems the sorting is not working as expected.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST.TABLENAME STORED AS ORC AS
(
COUNTRY INT,
YEAR STRING,
In_stock INT,
ZONE STRING,
TRANS_DT STRING,
|
|
MORE COLUMNS
)
FROM SOURCETABLE PARTITION BY (YEAR,IN_STOCK)

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE TEST.TABLENAME PARTITION(YEAR, IN_STOCK)
SELECT
|
|
FROM SOURCETABLE CLUSTER BY trans_dt;



SELECT
a.country,
a.zone,
collect_set(a.prod_id) AS prod_seq
count(*) as count
FROM SOURCETABLE WHERE IN_STCK=1
GROUP BY
a.country,
a.zone
;
```

Comment: How did you check that sorting is not working as expected?  Please include that part too And please add more details about what is expected.

Comment: @leftjoin im not getting collect_set items as per trans_dt. will partitioning affect sorting in this case ? if not how sorting will work here ? trans_dt will be sorted within partition?

Comment: sorting will work during insert into ORC. But how it related to collect_set? And please answer previous questions.

Comment: @leftjoin sorting is not working as expected bcoz I m not getting ascending order sequence of products in collect_set .. essentially I want trans_dt to be sorted within zones for each country in optimized way currently it is taking too much time to do sorting and seems sorting is not working as expected i.e within zones.

Comment: What I can understand is that you have some query with collect_set, right? And you think that query which is impossible to fathom from what you are saying is somehow related to insert+cluster by query you have provided. I tell you what: It is not related at all. sorting in array is determined ONLY by the query you are doing collect_set, not INSERT query. To sort array you need to have sort in the query you are doing SELECT collect_set

Comment: Using sorting during insert you can improve packing of table data, improve internal orc indexes efficiency, but this does not imply that some select will return data sorted if you will not sort in the select. There is no such thing as sorted table which will return sorted dataset when selected

Comment: @leftjoin example prod1- 201609, prod2-201606 cluster by should show prod2-201606 as 1st row and prod1- 201609 2nd row , but it is not showing in ascending order hence when I do collect_set on prod I get prod2 as 1st item whereas prod1 as second, Ideally it should be opposite. So it seems sorting has some issue.

Comment: Am I the only one who could not find any SELECT query with collect_set in your question? Something with my browser then.

Comment: @leftjoin select query added

Comment: There is no any sort in the query. collect_set will return data not necessarily sorted as it is stored in the table. Table is being read splitted and in parallel. dtat returned sorted only if there is sort is in the query. Does not matter how did you sort table during insert.

Comment: See this answer about how to sort array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57392965/2700344

Comment: Also see this answer about ordered data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56567967/2700344